# how to display an answer from dominant radiobutton that checked in every questio*?

Tags: java, android

i'v 3 radiobuttons in every question in my program, but i dont know how to display the answer based on how many radiobutton selected. pls help

**here is the xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPrev"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="&lt;&lt;" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSelesai"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Selesai" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text=">>" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNama"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHalaman"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTanggal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewWaktu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTanggal"
    android:text="TextView" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSoal2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSoal2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gambarKuis"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gambarKuis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewWaktu"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/girl" />
```

**here's the database.java :**

```
 package com.example.user.personalitytest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by User on 14/06/2016.
 */
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    final static String DB_NAME = "db_soalgayabelajar";

    public Database(Context contex){
        super(contex,DB_NAME,null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTX tbl_soal(id INTEGERid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, soal TEXT, pil_a TEXT, pil_b TEXT, pil_c TEXT, jwban INTEGER, img BLOB)";
        db.execSQL(sql);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("soal", "1.\tKalau ada orang yang meminta petunjuk jalan, biasanya saya akan..");
        values.put("pil_a", "Menggambar peta jalan pada sebuah kertas");
        values.put("pil_b","Memberitahu secara lisan (melalui ucapan)");
        values.put("pil_c","Mencoba memberitahu dengan isyarat tangan atau langsung mengantarnya");
        values.put("jwban","1");
        db.insert("tbl_soal", "soal", values);

        values.put("soal", "2.\tSaya paling suka permainan..");
        values.put("pil_a", "Kata Bergambar.");
        values.put("pil_b","Acak Kata");
        values.put("pil_c", "Pantomin");
        values.put("jwban","2");
        db.insert("tbl_soal", "soal", values);



 values.put("soal", "3.\tSaya ingin sekali menonton film bioskop karena…");
        values.put("pil_a", "tMelihat cover iklan yang menarik");
        values.put("pil_b","Membaca synopsis cerita");
        values.put("pil_c", "c.\tMenonton potongan film");
        values.put("jwban","1");
        db.insert("tbl_soal", "soal", values);





values.put("soal", "4.\tSaya punya guru favorit. Saat mengajar, ia selalu menggunakan..");
            values.put("pil_a", "Ceramah, diskusi, dan debat");
            values.put("pil_b","Diagram, bagan,alur, dan slide");
            values.put("pil_c", "Trial, uji coba, dan praktik ");
            values.put("jwban","0");
            db.insert("tbl_soal", "soal", values);

            values.put("soal", "5.\tKetika bicara, biasanya saya paling suka…");
            values.put("pil_a", "tsuka berbicara, perlahan, dan jelas, tetapi tidak suka mendengarkan terlalu lama");
            values.put("pil_b","tsuka mendengarkan orang lain berbicara, baru kemudian berbicara");
        values.put("pil_c", "tberbicara dengan menggunakan bahasa tubuh dan gerakan yang banyak");
        values.put("jwban","1");
        db.insert("tbl_soal", "soal", values);

        values.put("soal", "6.\tsebelum mengerjakan sesuatu, saya biasanya..");
        values.put("pil_a", "membaca instruksinya terlebih dahulu");
        values.put("pil_b","mendengarkan instruksi dari orang lain, baru mengerjakan");
        values.put("pil_c", "c.\tlangsung melakukan uji coba");
        values.put("jwban","2");
        db.insert("tbl_soal", "soal", values);

        values.put("soal", "7.\tketika lupa sesuatu, biasanya saya…");
        values.put("pil_a", "berusaha mengingat dari gambaran bentuk warna, atau cirinya");
        values.put("pil_b","berusaha mengingat dari ciri suaranya");
        values.put("pil_c", "berusaha mengingat apa yang dilakukan dan penggunaannya");
        values.put("jwban","2");
        db.insert("tbl_soal", "soal", values);

        values.put("soal", "8.\thal yang paling bias saya ingat dari seseorang adalah..");
        values.put("pil_a", "ekspresi wajah yang menawan");
        values.put("pil_b","suaranya yang khas");
        values.put("pil_c", "gerakan tubuhnya yang memukau");
        values.put("jwban","2");
        db.insert("tbl_soal", "soal", values);

        values.put("soal", "9.\tsaat berkomunikasi, saya suka kalau…");
        values.put("pil_a", "bertemu secara langsung");
        values.put("pil_b","bicara melalui telephon");
        values.put("pil_c", "bertemu dalam sebuah kegiatan aktif");
        values.put("jwban","2");
        db.insert("tbl_soal", "soal", values);

        values.put("soal", "10.\tkemampuan yang saya bias dan paling saya suka adalah..");
        values.put("pil_a", "a.\tmenggambar, melukis, atau mewarnai");
        values.put("pil_b","b.\tbernyanyi atau bermain alat music");
        values.put("pil_c", "c.\tmenari atau beladiri");
        values.put("jwban","2");
        db.insert("tbl_soal", "soal", values);


        String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_gambar(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama TEXT, img BLOB)";
        db.execSQL(sql2);

        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put("nama", "Tipe Visual (Dominan A)" +
                "Tipe visual adalah tipe orang yang cenderung menerima informasi paling banyak dan palinh efektif menggunakan indera penglihatan (visual).\n" +
                "Strategi belajar yang cocok bagi tipe visual:\n" +
                "1.\tgunakanlah variasi warna dalam melakukan pencatatan, seperti memberi garis bawah atau gmembuat grafik.\n" +
                "2.\tMayoritas, tipe visual suka membaca. Namun, buku bacaan yang banyak memiliki gambar ilustrasi dan warna yang menarik lebih mudah dipahami daripada buku bacaan yang penuh dengan teks.\n" +
                "3.\tPerhatikan penerangan saan belajar san hindari “polusi visual”\n" +
                "4.\tSaat mengingat sesuatu, bayangkan danbuat tulisan yang memudahkan.\n" +
                "5.\tCatat kembali bahan pelajaran dengan warna dan gambar yang manarik.\n");
        db.insert("tbl_gambar", "nama", v);

        v.put("nama", "Tipe Auditiry (Domiinan B)" +
                "Tipe auditory adalah tipe orang yang cenderung menerika informasi paling banyak dan paling efektif menggunakan indera pendengaran (Audio).\n" +
                "Strategi belajar yang cocok bagi tipe auditory :\n" +
                "1.\tGunakanlah voice recorder atau perekam suara saat mendengarkan pelajaran.\n" +
                "2.\tPerbanyak melakukan presentasi dan Tanya jawab.\n" +
                "3.\tLagukan apa yang diingat dengan irama dan hindari “polusi suara” (kebisingan).\n" +
                "4.\tBerpikir dan mengingat sambil mengucapkanya kembali.\n" +
                "5.\tDengarkan kembali pelajaran melalui rekaman atau penjelasan orang lain.\n");
        db.insert("tbl_gambar", "nama", v);
        v.put("nama", "Tipe Kinestetik (Dominan C)" +
                "Tipe kinestetik adalah tipe orang yang cenderung menerima informasi paling banyak dan paling efektif dengan melibatkan gerakan tubuh, peragaan dan aktivitas fisik.\n" +
                "Strategi belajar yang cocok bagi tipe kinestetik:" +
                "1.\tGunakanlah gerakan dalam pelajaran, seperti aktivitas atau uji coba secara langsung.\n" +
                "2.\tPerbanyak praktik yang berkaitan dengan pelajaran (praktik di laboratorium( dan langsung bias diaplikasikan.\n" +
                "3.\tHindari belajar yang monoton (terlalu banyak duduk).\n" +
                "4.\tSaat mengingat sesuatu, lakukanlah hal yang diingat dengan aktivitas gerak.\n" +
                "5.\tMenulis diudara, gunakan gerak imajinatif.\n");
        db.insert("tbl_gambar", "nama", v);
    }
    public List<Soal> getSoal(){
        List<Soal> listSoal = new ArrayList<Soal>();
        String query = "select * from tbl_soal";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Soal s = new Soal();
                s.setSoal(cursor.getString(1));
                s.setPil_a(cursor.getString(2));
                s.setPil_b(cursor.getString(3));
                s.setPil_c(cursor.getString(4));
                s.setJwban(cursor.getInt(5));
                s.setGambar(cursor.getInt(6));
                listSoal.add(s);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return listSoal;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_soal");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_gambar");
        onCreate(db);
        }
}
```

**the other .java:**

```
package com.example.user.personalitytest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * Created by User on 14/06/2016.
 */
public class Pgdominan extends Activity {

    private Database db;
    private TextView txtnama, txtno, txttanggal, txtwaktu, txtsoal;
    private RadioGroup rg;
    private RadioButton rdA, rdB, rdC;
    private List<Soal> listSoal;
    private int detik = 120000; // --> 10 menit
    private Button btnPrev, btnNext, btnSelesai;
    int jawabanYgDiPilih[] = null;
    int jawabanYgBenar[] = null;
    boolean cekPertanyaan = false;
    int urutanPertanyaan = 0;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pgdominan);
        db = new Database(this);
        txtnama = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNama);
        txtno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHalaman);
        txttanggal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTanggal);
        txtwaktu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWaktu);
        txtsoal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSoal2);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rdA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdC = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        btnPrev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrev);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnSelesai = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelesai);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        txttanggal.setText(Integer.toString(day) + "-" + Integer.toString(month + 1) + "-" + Integer.toString(year));

        int score=0;
        if (rdA.isChecked()) score +=3;
        if (rdB.isChecked()) score +=2;
        if (rdC.isChecked()) score +=1;

        listSoal = new ArrayList<Soal>();
        listSoal = db.getSoal();

        btnSelesai.setOnClickListener(klikSelesai);
        btnPrev.setOnClickListener(klikSebelum);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(klikBerikut);
        //new GetSoal().execute();
        jawabanYgDiPilih = new int[listSoal.size()];
        java.util.Arrays.fill(jawabanYgDiPilih, -2);
        jawabanYgBenar = new int[listSoal.size()];
        java.util.Arrays.fill(jawabanYgBenar, -1);
        showInputUser();

    }

    private void showInputUser() {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.nama, null);

        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        dialog.setView(v);
        dialog.setTitle("Ketikkan Nama Anda");
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.girl);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        final Button btnOk = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
        final EditText inputUser = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextNama);


        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (inputUser.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Isi dooong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    txtnama.setText(inputUser.getText().toString());
                    mulaiKuis();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }

    protected void mulaiKuis() {
        setUpWaktu();
        setUpSoal();

    }

    private void setUpWaktu() {
        CounterClass mCountDownTimer = new CounterClass(detik, 1000);
        mCountDownTimer.start();
    }

    private void setUpSoal() {
        Collections.shuffle(listSoal);
        this.tunjukanPertanyaan(0, cekPertanyaan);
    }

    private void tunjukanPertanyaan(int urutan_soal_soal, boolean cekPertanyaan) {
        btnSelesai.setEnabled(false);
        try {
            rg.clearCheck();
            Soal soal = new Soal();
            soal = listSoal.get(urutan_soal_soal);
            String pertanyaan = soal.getSoal();
            if (jawabanYgBenar[urutan_soal_soal] == -1) {
                jawabanYgBenar[urutan_soal_soal] = soal.getJwban();
            }
            int gambar = soal.getGambar();
            txtsoal.setText(pertanyaan.toCharArray(), 0, pertanyaan.length());
            rg.check(-1);
            String jwb_a = soal.getPil_a();
            rdA.setText(jwb_a.toCharArray(), 0,
                    jwb_a.length());
            String jwb_b = soal.getPil_b();
            rdB.setText(jwb_b.toCharArray(), 0,
                    jwb_b.length());
            String jwb_c = soal.getPil_c();
            rdC.setText(jwb_c.toCharArray(), 0,
                    jwb_c.length());

            Log.d("", jawabanYgDiPilih[urutan_soal_soal] + "");
            if (jawabanYgDiPilih[urutan_soal_soal] == 0)
                rg.check(R.id.radio0);
            if (jawabanYgDiPilih[urutan_soal_soal] == 1)
                rg.check(R.id.radio1);
            if (jawabanYgDiPilih[urutan_soal_soal] == 2)
                rg.check(R.id.radio2);

            pasangLabelDanNomorUrut();

            if (urutan_soal_soal == (listSoal.size() - 1)) {
                btnNext.setEnabled(false);
                btnSelesai.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if (urutan_soal_soal == 0)
                btnPrev.setEnabled(false);

            if (urutan_soal_soal > 0)
                btnPrev.setEnabled(true);

            if (urutan_soal_soal < (listSoal.size() - 1))
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());

        }
    }


}
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
        public CounterClass(long millisFuture, long countDownInterval){
            super(millisFuture,countDownInterval);

        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            aturJawaban_nya();
            //hitung yang dominan
            int jumlahJawabanYgBenar = 0;
            for (int i = 0;i < jawabanYgBenar.length; i++) {
                if ((jawabanYgBenar[i] != -1) && (jawabanYgBenar[i] == jawabanYgDiPilih[i]))
                    jumlahJawabanYgBenar++;
                if(jawabanYgBenar[i] != jawabanYgDiPilih[i])
                    noSalah = noSalah+" " + Integer.toString(i+1);
            }
            if(noSalah == ""){
                noSalah = "Benar semua";
            }
            else{
                noSalah = "No yang salah"+noSalah;
            }
            AlertDialog tampilKotakAlert;
            tampilKotakAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            tampilKotakAlert.setTitle("Nilai");
            tampilKotakAlert.setMessage("Benar " +jumlahJawabanYgBenar + " dari "
                    + (listSoal.size() +" soal. "+noSalah));

            tampilKotakAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Lagi",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            cekPertanyaan = false;
                            urutanPertanyaan = 0;
                            noSalah="";
                            java.util.Arrays.fill(jawabanYgDiPilih, -2);
                            MainActivity.this.tunjukanPertanyaan(0,
                                    cekPertanyaan);
                        }
                    });

            tampilKotakAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Keluar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            cekPertanyaan = false;
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

            tampilKotakAlert.show();
        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toMinutes(millis)));
            txtwaktu.setText(hms);
        }
    }
        private OnClickListener klikSelesai = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                aturJawaban_nya();
                // hitung berapa yg benar
                int jumlahJawabanYgBenar = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < jawabanYgBenar.length; i++) {
                    if ((jawabanYgBenar[i] != -1) && (jawabanYgBenar[i] == jawabanYgDiPilih[i]))
                        jumlahJawabanYgBenar++;
                    if(jawabanYgBenar[i] != jawabanYgDiPilih[i])
                        noSalah = noSalah+" " + Integer.toString(i+1);
                }
                if(noSalah == ""){
                    noSalah = "Benar semua";
                }
                else{
                    noSalah = "No yang salah"+noSalah;
                }
                AlertDialog tampilKotakAlert;
                tampilKotakAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                tampilKotakAlert.setTitle("Nilai");
                tampilKotakAlert.setMessage("Benar " +jumlahJawabanYgBenar + " dari "
                        + (listSoal.size() +" soal. "+noSalah));

                tampilKotakAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Lagi",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                cekPertanyaan = false;
                                urutanPertanyaan = 0;
                                noSalah="";
                                java.util.Arrays.fill(jawabanYgDiPilih, -2);
                                MainActivity.this.tunjukanPertanyaan(0,
                                        cekPertanyaan);
                            }
                        });

                tampilKotakAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Keluar",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                cekPertanyaan = false;
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

                tampilKotakAlert.show();

            }
        };

        private void aturJawaban_nya() {
            if (rdA.isChecked())
                jawabanYgDiPilih[urutanPertanyaan] = 0;
            if (rdB.isChecked())
                jawabanYgDiPilih[urutanPertanyaan] = 1;
            if (rdC.isChecked())
                jawabanYgDiPilih[urutanPertanyaan] = 2;

            Log.d("", Arrays.toString(jawabanYgDiPilih));
            Log.d("", Arrays.toString(jawabanYgBenar));

        }

        private OnClickListener klikBerikut = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                aturJawaban_nya();
                urutanPertanyaan++;
                if (urutanPertanyaan >= listSoal.size())
                    urutanPertanyaan = listSoal.size() - 1;

                tunjukanPertanyaan(urutanPertanyaan, cekPertanyaan);
            }
        };

        private OnClickListener klikSebelum = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                aturJawaban_nya();
                urutanPertanyaan--;
                if (urutanPertanyaan < 0)
                    urutanPertanyaan = 0;

                tunjukanPertanyaan(urutanPertanyaan, cekPertanyaan);
            }
        };

        private void pasangLabelDanNomorUrut() {
            txtno.setText("Soal ke-" + (urutanPertanyaan + 1) + " dari "
                    + listSoal.size());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change in your code insted of

```
 if (jawabanYgDiPilih[urutan_soal_soal] == 0)
            rg.check(R.id.radio0);
        if (jawabanYgDiPilih[urutan_soal_soal] == 1)
            rg.check(R.id.radio1);
        if (jawabanYgDiPilih[urutan_soal_soal] == 2)
            rg.check(R.id.radio2);
```

to

```
if (jawabanYgDiPilih[urutan_soal_soal] == 0)
            rdA.setChecked(true);;
        if (jawabanYgDiPilih[urutan_soal_soal] == 1)
            rdB.setChecked(true);;
        if (jawabanYgDiPilih[urutan_soal_soal] == 2)
            rdC.setChecked(true);;
```

Comment: sorry but thats not the poin :( i still cant get what i want